# How would I restart Apache using the Terminal in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal.app

This is what I’ve done but I’m really new to terminal:

```
Jeremys-MacBook-Pro-2:~ jeremyoconnor$ apachectl restart

This operation requires root.
```

Answer (score 24):

Since Apache runs on a reserved port (`80`) that is considered a sensitive system level port you would have to run `apachectl restart` via `sudo` like this:

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

After typing that in it will as you for your password. Assuming you have admin privileges, just type in the password and Apache should restart. Other commands include `start` and `stop` that can be run like this to start Apache:

```
sudo apachectl -k start
```

And like this to stop Apache:

```
sudo apachectl -k stop
```

Also, if you just type in `apachectl` without anything you will receive a list of options and directives you can use with the `apachectl` command; this is my output from Mac OS X 10.9.5:

```
Usage: /usr/sbin/httpd [-D name] [-d directory] [-f file]
                       [-C "directive"] [-c "directive"]
                       [-k start|restart|graceful|graceful-stop|stop]
                       [-v] [-V] [-h] [-l] [-L] [-t] [-T] [-S]
Options:
  -D name            : define a name for use in <IfDefine name> directives
  -d directory       : specify an alternate initial ServerRoot
  -f file            : specify an alternate ServerConfigFile
  -C "directive"     : process directive before reading config files
  -c "directive"     : process directive after reading config files
  -e level           : show startup errors of level (see LogLevel)
  -E file            : log startup errors to file
  -v                 : show version number
  -V                 : show compile settings
  -h                 : list available command line options (this page)
  -l                 : list compiled in modules
  -L                 : list available configuration directives
  -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS  : show parsed settings (currently only vhost settings)
  -S                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
  -t -D DUMP_MODULES : show all loaded modules 
  -M                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_MODULES
  -t                 : run syntax check for config files
  -T                 : start without DocumentRoot(s) check
```